# PHP and events - flush to client does not happen until the script dies

Tags: php, eventsource

I am trying to create a simple page that sends events to a web page but I cannot get the PHP to send the output before the page terminates.

I am using PHP-FPM and php5.6.27.

this is my simple HTML page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test events</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        testing events
        <ul id="pingEventList" style="float: left"></ul>
        <ul id="messageEventList" style="float: left"></ul>
        <script>
            var evtSource=new EventSource("./s_events.php?auth=e3b164ef33d802c45da829b8f1240d16");
            var pingEventList=document.getElementById('pingEventList');
            var messageEventList=document.getElementById('messageEventList');
            evtSource.onmessage=function (e){
                var newElement=document.createElement("li");
                newElement.innerHTML="message: "+e.data;
                messageEventList.appendChild(newElement);
            };
            evtSource.addEventListener("initial", function (e){
                var newElement=document.createElement("li");
//              var obj=JSON.parse(e.data);
                newElement.innerHTML="initial info "+e.data;
                console.log("initial info "+e.data);
                pingEventList.appendChild(newElement);
            }, false);
            evtSource.addEventListener("modified", function (e){
                var newElement=document.createElement("li");
//              var obj=JSON.parse(e.data);
                newElement.innerHTML="modified info "+e.data;
                console.log("modified info "+e.data);
                pingEventList.appendChild(newElement);
            }, false);
            evtSource.onerror=function (e){
                console.log("EventSource failed.", e);
//              while(pingEventList.firstChild){
//                  pingEventList.removeChild(pingEventList.firstChild);
//              }
//              alert("EventSource failed.");
            };
//          evtSource.close();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my PHP page:

```
<?php

@set_time_limit(0); // Disable time limit
// Prevent buffering
if(function_exists('apache_setenv')){
    @apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
}
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
@ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
while(ob_get_level() !=0){
    ob_end_flush();
}
ob_implicit_flush(1);
ignore_user_abort(false);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); // recommended to prevent caching of event data.
header('X-Accel-Buffering: off'); // Disables FastCGI Buffering on Nginx
$sleep_time          = 1; //0.5  // seconds to sleep after the data has been sent
$exec_limit_time     = 15; //600;  // the time limit of the script in seconds
$keep_alive_time     = 30; //300;  // The interval of sending a signal to keep the connection alive
$client_reconnect    = 1;  // the time client to reconnect after connection has lost in seconds
$keep_alive_start    = time();
$exec_limit_start    = time();


$ts_last_used    = intval(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_LAST_EVENT_ID"])?$_SERVER["HTTP_LAST_EVENT_ID"]:0);
echo 'retry:'.($client_reconnect*1000)."\n";
$event           = [
    'id'     => $ts_last_used++,
    'event'  => 'initial',
    'data'   => "[\ndata:".'INITIAL DATA'."\ndata:]",
];
_send_event_data($event);
while(1){
    // Did the connection fail?
    if(connection_status() !=CONNECTION_NORMAL){
        break;
    }else{
        $event = [
            'id'     => $ts_last_used++,
            'event'  => 'modified',
            'data'   => '{"id":"stuff here too"}',
        ];
        _send_event_data($event);
    }
    // Sleep for x seconds
    usleep($sleep_time*1000000);
    if($exec_limit_start+$exec_limit_time<time()){
        break;
    }
    if($keep_alive_start+$keep_alive_time<time()){
        $keep_alive_start = time();
        echo ': '.sha1(mt_rand())."\n\n";
    }
}
// If this is reached, then the 'break'
// was triggered from inside the while loop
//
// So here we can log, or perform any other tasks
// we need without actually being dependent on the
// browser.

function _send_event_data($info){
    global $keep_alive_start;
    if(isset($info['id'])){
        echo 'id:'.$info['id']."\n";
    }
    if(isset($info['event'])){
        echo 'event:'.$info['event']."\n";
    }
    echo 'data:'.$info['data']."\n";
    if(!isset($info['more_to_come'])||!$info['more_to_come']){
        echo "\n";
    }
    $keep_alive_start = time();
    @ob_end_flush();
    flush();
}
```

I have tried various possible solutions, but I cannot figure it out.  I have also changed PHP-FPM to mod_php (I am using apache) just in case it was PHP_FPM, but I didn't have any success.

I am open to suggestions

Comment: Errors? Expected result? ....

Comment: no errors at all, the page outputs only when the script ends and not while the script is running.  There is no data sent to the client at all until the timeout set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out... it was apache that was holding the output, this is my new configuration for fast-cgi usign php-fpm:

```
<IfModule fastcgi_module>
   #php-fpm
   AddHandler php5-fcgi .php .html
   Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
   Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/local/www/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
   FastCgiExternalServer /usr/local/www/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -flush -socket /var/run/php-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 600
   <Directory /usr/local/www/cgi-bin>
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

What made the difference was the `-flush` added to `FastCgiExternalServer`, now the output is not buffered anymore and it output right away (I was able to find the answer thanks to this page: http://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2016/streaming-php-disabling-output-buffering-php-apache-nginx-and-varnish )